# Cloudflare API - Curl request to block IP with IP Access Rules

Tags: php, cloudflare

I manually block IP to access my site ([dlandroid.com](https://dlandroid.com/)) with Cloudflare "IP Access Rules",
My question is how to block an IP with Cloudflare API Curl request using PHP?

I search API document and find this but don't know how to use it with PHP:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/firewall/access_rules/rules?page=1&per_page=20&mode=challenge&configuration.target=ip&configuration.value=198.51.100.4&notes=my note&match=all&order=mode&direction=desc" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

also check this: https://api.cloudflare.com/#firewall-access-rule-for-a-zone-list-access-rules

Comment: *"I search API document and find this but don't know how to use it with PHP:"* [cloudflare api php](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cloudflare+api+php) first result on Google is a PHP api on github which is from Cloudflare them self .. [Cloudflare PHP API Binding](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001661191)